# Unable to understand what jdk location is

Tags: java, eclipse, settings, location

I have java installed correctly for sure.

```
aaa@ubuntu:~$ whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/X11/java /usr/local/java /usr/share/java
aaa@ubuntu:~$ whereis javac
javac: /usr/bin/javac /usr/bin/X11/javac
```

But when I'm trying to add the location of `/usr/bin/java` in IntellyJ Idea12 as a java project sdk, I can't do that because it requires the folder and `/usr/bin/java` is a file. Even if I specify `/usr/bin`, it says that it's not a valid location.

So where is it located and how do I setup a location to be a java sdk for IntellyJ Idea12 or for Eclipse?

**UPDATE**:
The path "/usr/lib/jvm/" doesn't exist

**UPDATE2**:

I used this tutorial http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux

Comment: How did you install `jdk`, using `update-alternatives` might help you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

All ubuntu JRE and JDK installs gets stored in `/usr/lib/jvm/`.

You need to add the multi-arch specific JDK location to Idea12.
For example, on 32-bit x86 Ubuntu installations, use `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386`.

Comment: The path " /usr/lib/jvm/" doesn't exist.

Comment: /usr/lib/jvm/ exist after you have installed the **openjdk-7-jdk** package. You can see this for yourself if you use the ubuntu package search and search for javac http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=quantal&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=javac

Comment: didn't I install it? Look at my update2

Comment: You need to use the /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_17 if you have followed the tutorial mentioned in UPDATE2.I recommend you to follow the Ubuntu Java help documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Comment: Thanks. I just `ls -lh /usr/lib/jvm/` and discover wich Java. Expected `default-java`but found `java-7-oracle`. Solved.

Answer (score -1):

[**whereis**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/whereis.1.html) locates source/binary and manuals sections for specified files. Then supplied  names  are first stripped of leading pathname components and any (single) trailing extension of the form .ext, for example,.c. Prefixes  of  s.   resulting  from  use of source code control are also dealt with.  **whereis** then attempts to locate the desired program  in  a list of standard Linux places.

```
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/X11/java /usr/local/java /usr/share/java
```

That is just a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) of java installation. you can read [here](http://www.jusuchyne.com/codingforme/2012/08/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-and-path-in-linux/)